# How to Program Task Bar Add-on (NOT Systray Icon)

Tags: windows, taskbar

I am looking to write a small application that will reside as a button on the Task Bar in Windows (it's fine if it is only compatible with Win7+), but I cannot figure out where to start to to put a widget onto the task bar itself.

See this attached image, taken from an HP laptop where the custom support center is overlayed on the task bar: [image]

Note, this is not a standard application icon that exists in the system tray. Nor is it your standard taskbar button, i.e. a pinned shortcut. It is a custom program of some sort that registers this item on the task bar.  I've seen similar things on other machines where the battery indicator is there, and has the current charge (before Windows 7 added an icon for that).

I am looking to position an interactive element at the start of the task bar like this one (only in a different position, more left, next to the start button).  I have been looking high and low for documentation to help me get started with this element, and I cannot find anything.  Can anyone provide a hint on how to get started?

I can write in C#, C++, whatever, so just a pointer to the right spot would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: I had that exact same question, thanks for asking. :)

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is `TaskBar Toolbar`, I think; you can create a new one in Windows itself by right-clicking the TaskBar and choosing `Toolbars->New Toolbar`, so it's probably based on creating a shortcut in a specific folder. The ones just to the right of the Start Button are `pinned applications`.

Comment: The magic phrase is "deskband".